# How to pass in a variable value in XPATH element using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
test = "Games"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title = {test}]").click()
```

My code doesn't work. Please suggest how to pass in a variable value inside the XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = "Games"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title = {}]".format(test)).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with respect to the variable value attribute of the  tag using Selenium and python you can use either of the following Locator Strategies:

Using variable in `XPATH:`

```
state = 'AL-Alabama'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='" +state+ "']").click()
Using %s in XPATH:

state = 'AL-Alabama'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='%s']"% str(state)).click()
Using format() in XPATH:

state = 'AL-Alabama'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[@value='{}']".format(str(state))).click()
```